# MYSQL find max value

Tags: mysql

Take a MYSQL table like this :

```
id:prod1, priceA:10, priceB:20, priceC:30,priceD:18,...
id:prod2, priceA:22, priceB:20, priceC:30,priceD:78,...
id:prod3, priceA:4, priceB:20, priceC:30,priceD:19,...
```

I'm trying to select all ids where priceA is the lowest of the 3 prices, in this case, prod1 and prod3

I have tried to use max() but it acts only on one field.

I was thinking of something along the lines of :

`SELECT id from table WHERE priceA < priceB AND priceA < priceC...`, but in real life, there's 20 prices columns so it's highly unpractical...

Could anyone tell me if there is a function I don't know about that would simplify my query?

Comment: You have a problem in the design of your table. You should have two tables, one with products and one for pricesbyproduct, with a product ID and n Prices for that particular product. Then your query will be very simple.

Comment: If I could, I would, but the big picture is a bit more complicated than that. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can consider using the LEAST function. Still, you would have to list all the price columns, as below:

```
SELECT id
FROM table
WHERE priceA = LEAST(priceA, priceB, priceC);
```

Please see the **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0037f6/1)**.